# Предложив заменить "замузганный" на "замызганный", я обобрала автора на целую лексему?

Tags: просторечия, диалектизмы

> И зимой и летом — всегда — Чайка носит светлый **замызганный** плащ.
>   За длительное время он превратился у него в настоящий домашний халат,
>   исполненный в восточном вкусе.

Было-то ***у***. А я навязала ***ы***...

Теперь совесть не спокойна, хотя словари на моей стороне.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что некоторые пользователи сети бессознательно комбинируют _зам**ы**зганный_ с _зам**у**соленным_. В книгах гугл находит всего 4 (!) случая употреления, из них 3 у современных малоизвестных авторов (возможно, просто ослабленный корректорский контроль) и 1 в неких "революционных очерках" (можно допустить новояз).

Comment: Думаю, особой разницы нет, т.к. оба слова являются разговорными и, соответственно, не имеют чётких показаний к употреблению.

Comment: Возможно, это _диалектное_ отклонение, можно поискать в словарях региональных говоров.

Comment: В _вологодской_ летописи попалось: "А ты вели-ко ему да замузгать ему во целой свист!" https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/letopis/text1.pdf

Comment: Здесь (где во целой свист) смысл совсем новый: поприналечь изо всех щенячьих сил / во весь опор, типа..

Comment: Поиск в [корпусе русского языка](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html) находит 65 употреблений слова "замызганный", и ни одного - слова "замузганный".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Замы́згать** — *прост.* загрязнить, истрепать при носке, использовании;
   **заму́рзать** — *разг.* сильно испачкать.
   Возможно, заму́згать (заму́зганный) — это симбиоз двух слов (вообще-то всем понятный)?
2. Вот [тут](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtwY62iKziAhUSqIsKHVTEAuEQvgUIKSgB&biw=1366&bih=651) нашлось:
   *На самом деле МЪ — древний корень со значением "нечто пастообразное, грязь"; отсюда всякого рода глаголы типа МЫЗгать, заМУЗгать, МАЗать.*

[В. А. Чудинов. Расшифровка славянского слогового и буквенного письма](http://chudinov.ru/shok-ot-vida-monografii-gs-grinevicha/)